# How to obtain $||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$ from $|x|-|y|\le |x-y|$?

Tags: inequality, absolute-value

Having the following inequality:
$$|x|-|y|\le |x-y|$$
does it imply that $||x|-|y||\le|x-y|$ if it does (i think it does) how to prove it?

Comment: Consider three cases: $\lvert x\rvert <\lvert y\rvert$, $\lvert x\rvert = \lvert y\rvert$, and $\lvert x\rvert > \lvert y\rvert$.

Comment: mea culpa, i am sorry

Comment: @kurkowski - Not your fault. It took me a while to find.

Answer (score 0):

The triangle inequality is $$|a+b|\le|a|+|b|.$$ Let $a=x-y$ and $b=y$. Then $a+b=x$. Our above inequality becomes $$|x|\le|x-y|+|y|.$$ Now subtract $|y|$ on both sides to arrive at your result.